# Input string from user, but length of string user wants to input is not known to me

Tags: c++

It might be a basic question, but i could not find a proper answer anywhere...

Q) Suppose I declare a string a[10], and i want to input it from user, but i don't know the length of string the user wants to input
What I applied was the following loop to take the input:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
{
    int a[10],i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
}
```

let the user wish to input a string of length 5 only, but with the above loop, the compiler would iterate only if the string length is 10...

Moreover, i am not allowed to ask the user the length of array he wants to input.

Comment: Declare the int array as a char array or a string(C++) and simply cin>>string;

Comment: You left out some languages in your tag list.

Comment: He's right, edit out the algorithm/java tag, most traffic will come from the java tag

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP seems to want solutions in multiple languages.

Comment: @MartinJames I have no clue what he wants. How do you know me wonders?

Comment: Learn about dynamic memory allocation using `new`.

Comment: @Martin James see I am new to this site, therefore, sorry for multiple tags

Comment: @CoolGuy I just tried that, but surprisingly.. no matter what the size decided by the `new` statement, the string only ends when the null character appears. I even tried `strlen` on it, and the size decided by `new` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Use `std::string` and crop the string to the maximum size (if
   necessary) after input.
2. Use OS API to read one character at a time until a terminating
   character is received.

The C++ input functions for `std::string` or `char []`, will read characters from the input stream until the terminating condition is met; **without regards to the quantity of characters**.  There is no method to limit the quantity, using the standard multi-character stream input functions. Thus you will need a dynamic data structure to read in the data, then crop to the amount you want, if necessary.

You can read one character at a time, in a loop, until the terminating character is entered or the quantity limit is reached.  Unless you are careful, the standard character input functions may ignore whitespace or buffer characters until the terminating character is received.

If you want more or finer control of the input, use an OS API  to read the characters in a loop.  You may have to *echo* the characters to the output stream.